# Cannot access memory allocated with malloc in a function from my main

Tags: c, function, pointers, return, malloc

As far as I know allocating memory with malloc in a function allows you to use that memory in main until you manually free it. I have a function that reads a MNISTI image file and creates a vector for each image in the form of an array of integers. This is the code:

```
int* readNextMNISTImage(const char* file_path) {
    static int current_image = 0;

    FILE* file = fopen(file_path, "rb");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file: %s\n", file_path);
        return NULL;
    }

    fseek(file, 16 + IMAGE_SIZE * current_image, SEEK_SET);

    int* vector = (int*)malloc(IMAGE_SIZE * sizeof(int));
    if (vector == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error allocating memory for image vector.\n");
        fclose(file);
        return NULL;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < IMAGE_SIZE; ++j) {
        uint8_t pixel;
        size_t bytesRead = fread(&pixel, sizeof(uint8_t), 1, file);
        if (bytesRead != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error reading pixel data.\n");
            free(vector);
            fclose(file);
            return NULL;
        }
        vector[j] = (int)pixel; // Store pixel value as an integer
    }
    for (int i=0;i<IMAGE_SIZE;i++)
    printf("%d ", vector[i]);
    fclose(file);
    current_image++;
    return vector;
}
```

If I add a for loop in this function that prints the contents of the vector array, I can see that it is created exactly how I want it. An array of bytes that take value from 0 to 255. All is well. I return the pointer to that array in my main function, and try to print it there the same way so I can see if it's usable and I get a seg fault. I imagine it is something very basic but I cannot figure out why. This is my main:

```
int main() {
    char file_path[256];    
    
    printf("Enter the path to the dataset file: ");
    scanf("%s", file_path);
    
    int* vector = readNextMNISTImage(file_path);
    for (int i = 0; i < IMAGE_SIZE; i++)
    printf("%d ", vector[i]);
    free(vector);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the casts; make sure you have `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Valgrind found no errors, I was already including stdlib and I removed the casts. Issue sadly still remains

Comment: After removing the file access with dummy stuff, I can't reproduce the problem. So I would guess the problem is actually in the file I/O or in some other code not posted.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED. I was missing a letter in the declaration of the function in my .h file....... I thought if that was the case the program would not compile. Sorry for the trouble everyone

Comment: Turn on **ALL** your compiler warnings, including the one that says you're calling a function with no prototype in scope :-) otherwise compiler assumes function returns int ... and in your case `int` is very different than `int *`. -- see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wmissing-prototypes

Comment: Thank you, you saved me! I was stucked with this problem for a week. But i don't understand, how this thing even compiled